# How can i search a json response to see if a value exists using linq?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have the following json response

```
{
  "Id": "1234",
  "Name": "Test",
  "Orders": [
    {
      "OrderId": "87654",
      "OrderDetails": {
        "OrdId": "1234",
        "Name": "Desk"
      }
    },
    {
      "OrderId": "54213",
      "OrderDetails": {
        "OrdId": "4321",
        "Name": "Table"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to search the list of orders to see if there is an OrderId of 87654. 
I can do with an array , but how can I do it with Linq ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post and add the code your using right now to deserialize (I hope you are doing that) and then search it?

Comment: I deserialize using the following                                                                                    public class OrderDetails
{
    public string OrdId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public OrderDetails OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}   deserialize JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json) :

Comment: use dynamic object for task.

Comment: You should edit your code into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dEfeC7)

You can use [`Newtonsoft`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to achieve it

```
var jsonData = "{ 'Id': '1234', 'Name': 'Test', 'Orders': [ {'OrderId': '87654', 'OrderDetails': { 'OrdId': '1234', 'Name': 'Desk' } }, { 'OrderId': '54213', 'OrderDetails': { 'OrdId': '4321','Name': 'Table' }}]}";

 var desirializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonData);
 var result = desirializedData.Orders.Where(p => p.OrderId == 87654);
        foreach(var master in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(master.OrderId + " " + master.OrderDetails.Name);
        }
```

Comment: The desrializedData is declared as dynamic , so I have the following               dynamic desirializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonData);   So how will I use that for result ?

Comment: **dynamic desirializedData** From my point of view, You should create new classes to be able to deserialize and access it as a property.

Answer (score 2):

You can deserialize the json string to a JObject using Newtonsoft.Json and then loop through the orders to get the OrderIDs.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach(var order in obj["Orders"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(order["OrderId"]);
}
```

or you can use the Where clause.

```
var myOrder = obj["Orders"].Where(x => x["OrderId"].ToString().Equals("87654")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you can print any property of that order,

```
Console.WriteLine(myOrder["OrderDetails"]["Name"].ToString());
// Prints: Desk
```

---

**Alternatively, you can:** also use classes to deserialize the json you have and query the orders.

```
public class OrderDetails
{
    public string OrdId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public OrderDetails OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\json.txt");
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var myOrder = obj.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderId.Equals("87654"));
    if (myOrder != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myOrder.OrderDetails.Name);
    }
}
```